# php cannot export excel

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I can't get the excel file from this request. why?

My code:

Angular:

```
//angular Service
//used to export button
this.exportExcel = function($scope){
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/Home/PPEConfigPeriod/GetFlowListToDataTable",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            data: { ppeFlowSelectCon : $scope.ppeFlowSelectCon, periodId : $scope.currentPeriod.ID, staff :  $scope.staff }
        }).success(function(data){
            if(data != null){
                //location.href=data;
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP:

```
public function GetFlowListToDataTable()
{
    $requestUrl = ApiUrls::getFlowListToDataTable;
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $ppeFlowSelectCon = $data->ppeFlowSelectCon;
    $fileName = "PPETrack_" . $data->staff->LoginName . "_" . date('Y-m-d');
    $postArray = array(
        "periodId" => $data->periodId
    );
    $result = servicePost($requestUrl, $postArray, $ppeFlowSelectCon);

    $newResult = array();
    foreach( $result as $key => $value){
        $newResult = get_object_vars($value);
    }

    exportExcel($newResult, array(), $fileName);

    //$this->ajaxReturn($result);
}


function exportExcel($data=array(), $title=array(), $filename='report'){
header("Content-type:application/octet-stream");
header("Accept-Ranges:bytes");
header("Content-type:application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=".$filename.".xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

if (!empty($title)){
    foreach ($title as $k => $v) {
        $title[$k]=iconv("UTF-8", "GB2312",$v);
    }
    $title= implode("\t", $title);
    echo "$title\n";
}
if (!empty($data)){
    foreach($data as $key=>$val){
        foreach ($val as $ck => $cv) {
            $data[$key][$ck]=iconv("UTF-8", "GB2312", $cv);
        }
        $data[$key]=implode("\t", $data[$key]);

    }
    echo implode("\n",$data);
}
```

And WebApi：

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("GetFlowListToDataTable")]
    public DataTable GetFlowListToDataTable(PPEFlowSelectCon selCon, Guid periodId)
    {
        return new ConfigPeriodFacade().GetFlowListToDataTable(selCon, periodId);                       
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the error?

Comment: Your angular script shows the data being sent to server as utf8, so do you need to run it server side through iconv? And what is actually being returned? A broken excel file? An error? Zilch?

Comment: it always hava a return value. it's return array() data;

Answer (score 1):

first of all,your code is very messy!try using comments so we can understand what you are doing.
connecting to an excel file is done with `odbc_connect`.like this:

```html
$excelFile = realpath('C:/ExcelData.xls');  //the path of the excel file is stored in a variable
$excelDir = dirname($excelFile);
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq=$excelFile;DefaultDir=$excelDir" , '', '');
```

[this article](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) will help you to get familiar with `odbc_connect()`.

Comment: I get the data from asp.net web api. the $result data always has value. but doesn't pop up the download file with excel